# How to handle iterating over array of child-types in Angular html?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I have an array of items that are similar to a FormControl - but each item is a child type of FormControl, each extending different methods for use. When I use *ngFor to iterate over an `array: FormControl[]` and call the child method inside, like so:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="formControl.type == 1">
    <button (click)="formControl.someFunction()">Type 1 function</button>
</ng-container>
```

I get a type error saying that `someFunction()` does not exist on FormControl. This makes sense to me, as it's correct, but how would I properly deal with this situation in Angular?

I have already tried creating a pipe that takes a `FormControl` and returns its child type, which works sometimes, but fails in an action expression (error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression).

Is there any way to cast inside the Html? Or is there another way I should type my array of formControls?  I tried (`ChildType1 | ChildType2 | ChildType3 | FormControl`) but that did not work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is access the child function inside the .ts file.

```
<button (click)="someFunction()">Type 1 function</button>
```

In .ts file

```
someFunction() {
  parent.childfunction()
}
```

Comment: yeah that definitely works, thanks. It is a little inconvenient to have to re-define all of those class functions again in the component. I was hoping that there was some typescript feature I didn't know about or understand, but I guess I'll take what I can get

Comment: Well I'm glad that it helped, but if you find something better do comment